# Using CSS filters in react-native

Tags: react-native

It seems that react-native doesn't implement CSS' [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property.

Is there a way to replicate those? Specifically I am looking for a way to change the following to an image, without creating a special image just for that:

- Brightness
- Hue
- Saturation
- Blur

Answer (score 2):

Blur for images is already supported by RN via [blurRadius](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#blurradius) prop. The remaining filters you can find in my [react-native-color-matrix-image-filters](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-color-matrix-image-filters#supported-filters) library:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { Saturate } from 'react-native-color-matrix-image-filters';

const SaturatedImage = ({ saturate, ...imageProps }) => (
  <Saturate value={saturate}>
    <Image {...imageProps} />
  </Saturate>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Update RN 0.62.2:
I was using above mentioned Library `react-native-color-matrix-image-filters`, but I was looking for web support too. As of right now React Native for web supports the css filter property: https://github.com/ndbroadbent/react-native-web/blob/91e4528eac16e10fd3d42644fc4c0c8047bee1bd/docs/components/View.md
For iOS and Android this style property does not work.